# How to setup password to Magento Cloud database?

Tags: magento2, database, password, magento2-cloud

My Magento Cloud doesn't have any passwords. I checked it in my `app/etc/env.php` file, and when I ran this command below.

```
php -r 'print_r(json_decode(base64_decode($_ENV["MAGENTO_CLOUD_RELATIONSHIPS"])));'
```

[image: Magento Cloud database password]

How could I set up a password for my Magento Cloud installation?

Answer (score 0):

To add a password you need to change this configuration below in the file `.magento/services.yaml`.

From

```
mysql:
    type: mysql:10.0
    disk: 9192
```

To

```
mysql:
    type: mysql:10.0
    disk: 9192
    configuration:
      schemas:
        - main
      endpoints:
        mysql:
          default_schema: main
          privileges:
            main: admin
```

After that, you will need to adjust the user and password in your `app/etc/env.php`, you will find the user and password running this command below inside your instance.

```
php -r 'print_r(json_decode(base64_decode($_ENV["MAGENTO_CLOUD_RELATIONSHIPS"])));'
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/services-mysql.html#connect-to-the-database